# Как добавить поддержку Spring MVC в IntelIJ?

Tags: spring

Я могу при создании проекта выбрать Spring MVC, но тогда он создастся без maven. Так же я могу создать maven проект и подгрузить через pom.xml Spring MVC, но в таком случае загружаются просто библиотеки, проект не строится под Spring MVC, не создаются нужные папки и файлы типа web.xml. А если выбрать опцию Add Framework Support в проекте, то там нету того что мне нужно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0) Убедитесь что у вас стоит последняя версия [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)
1) Создаете проект с `Maven`
2) Во вкладке `Projects` нажимаете ПКМ на названии проекта и выбираете `Add Framework Support`
3) В появившемся окне выбираете нужные вам компоненты `Spring`

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так и делал, но у меня в Add Framework Support нету Spring почему-то, на скриншоте видно.

Comment: @mctraher777 Может у вас `Comunity Edition`, а не `Ultimate Edition`?

Comment: Только что проверил, Ultimate

Comment: @Попробуйте скачать последнюю версию с сайта jetbrains и повторите попытку. Я проверял на 2018.1 все работает.

Comment: Спасибо, после обновления появился Spring

Comment: @mctraher777 Если я смог помочь вам решить проблему, примите мой ответ поставив галочку.